# Get color heat from value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to get a color from a percentage.

My percentage values are between 0 and 200

What I would get is :

```
0% ==> Cold ( blue ) 100% ===> tiepid (green) , 200% == > Hot (Red)
```

I tried to adapt this [code snipped](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/7210513#gistcomment-2836554) to my case but colors are limited between green ( 0 ) and yellow ( 200% ) I don't know why.

```js
function percentageToColor(perc) {
    let max = 200;
    let min = 0;
    var base = max - min;
    if (perc > 200) {
      perc = 200;
    }
    if (perc > 0) {
      if (base == 0) {
        perc = 100;
      } else {
        perc = ((perc - min) / base) * 100;
      }
      var r,
        g,
        b = 0;
      if (perc < 101) {
        g = 255;
        r = Math.round(2.5 * perc);
      } else {
        r = 255;
        g = Math.round(510 - 2.5 * perc);
      }
      var h = r * 0x10000 + g * 0x100 + b * 0x1;
      return '#' + ('000000' + h.toString(16)).slice(-6);
    } else {
      return '#d1d1d1';
    }
  }
  var color = percentageToColor(20)
 
  document.getElementById('percent').style.backgroundColor=color
```

```css
div {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div id="percent"></div>
```

**Update**

I discover that is better to use `hsl` but how to adapt this to values from 0% to 200%

```
function percentageToColor(percentage, maxHue = 120, minHue = 0) {
  const hue = percentage * (maxHue - minHue) + minHue;
  return `hsl(${hue}, 100%, 50%)`;
}
```

Comment: In your first example, removing `if (perc > 200) {...}` should work (if you input a higher value eg `percentageToColor(400)`);. To make it work with a scale between 0 and 200 add `perc = perc * 2;` as the first thing in your function, then `percentageToColor(200)`);. will give you red

Comment: The `h` in HSL is hue and it ranges from 0 to 360. So why not multiply your value by 1.8 to adjust for that? (360 / 200)